# Comparing two strings and returning the number of matched words

Tags: clojure

I'm fairly new to Clojure, and in programming, in general.
Is there a way I can compare two strings word by word and then return the number of matched words in both strings? Also how can I count the numbers in a string?

Ex: 
comparing string1 "**Hello Alan and Max"** and string2 **"Hello Alan and Bob"** will return "3" (such as Hello Alan and are the words matched in both strings)
and finding the number of words in string1 will result in the number 4.

Thank you

Comment: Note that usually "how to implement specification X?" questions get closed for being too broad here, unless you show a specific problem with how *you* tried to implement that specification yourself. Which is to say -- in this being answered rather than closed, you got lucky. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down into some smaller problems:

> compare two strings **word by word**

First we'll need a way to take a string and return its words. One way to do this is to assume any whitespace is separating words, so we can use a regular expression with [`clojure.string/split`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split):

```
(defn string->words [s]
  (clojure.string/split s #"\s+"))

(string->words "Hello world, it's me, Clojure.")
=> ["Hello" "world," "it's" "me," "Clojure."]
```

> return the number of **matched words** in both strings

The easiest way I can imagine doing this is to build two [sets](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Sets), one to represent the set of words in both sentences, and finding the intersection of the two sets:

```
(set (string->words "a b c a b c d e f"))
=> #{"d" "f" "e" "a" "b" "c"} ;; #{} represents a set
```

And we can use the `clojure.set/intersection` function to find the intersection of two sets:

```
(defn common-words [a b]
  (let [a (set (string->words a))
        b (set (string->words b))]
    (clojure.set/intersection a b)))

(common-words "say you" "say me")
=> #{"say"}
```

To get the count of (matching) words, we can use the `count` function with the output of the above functions:

```
(count (common-words "say you" "say me")) ;; => 1
```

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. Another question please, how do I store the "count of matching words" in a variable?  In general, how do I store an arithmetic operation in a variable?

Comment: but `(common-words "me say" "say you")` would output `1`, while the correct answer is 0 (considering the first unmatched word index, inorder).

Comment: @Twistyfool2 You bind names to values in a `let` block. In the solution above, both `a` and `b` are bound to the sets that result of breaking each string into words, then, inside the `let` block, the values are used to compute the intersection. You can create your own function and use your own `let` blocks. See also: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do, is to compare word sequences' items pairwise, and count the number of items until the first mismatch. Here is an almost word for word translation of this:

```
(defn mismatch-idx [s1 s2]
  (let [w #"\S+"]
    (->> (map = (re-seq w s1) (re-seq w s2))
         (take-while true?)
         count)))

user> (mismatch-idx "a b c" "qq b c")
;;=> 0
user> (mismatch-idx "a b c" "a x c")
;;=> 1
user> (mismatch-idx "a b c" "a b x")
;;=> 2
```